# Why does Redis return a partially completed transaction?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a redis transaction using `multi` in a `watch` like this:

```
redis.watch('my-hash', 'my-normal-key', () => {
   redis
     .multi()
     .hset('my-hash', 'hash-key-1', 1)
     .hset('my-hash', 'hash-key-2', 2)
     .set('my-normal-key', 'test', NX)
     .exec((err, res) => {
        // err is null
        // res is an array with the results of the operations but only the set operation has a null res!
     })
});
```

I then run in high concurrency with multiple clients running the above commands. What I notice is that, sometimes, when either `my-hash` or `my-normal-key` is being changed in another client, the `res` from the `exec` command is `null`. This is totally correct and I can understand.

When the transaction executes successfully, `res` is an array in this form:

```
res = [
   [null, 0],     // [err, res] for hset('my-hash', 'hash-key-1', 1)
   [null, 0],     // [err, res] for hset('my-hash', 'hash-key-2', 2)
   [null, 'OK'],  // [err, res] for set('my-normal-key', 'test', NX)
]
```

However, at certain times, `res` returns something that looks like a partial failure like so:

```
res = [
   [null, 0],
   [null, 0],
   [null, 0],
   [null, null],   // the result of the set operation is null!
]
```

The result of the `set` operation returns `null`, which I assume implies that another client has made a change. But I couldn't simulate how the results could be returned this way. I see in the eventual data in Redis that this does indeed complete all the `hset` operations except for the set operation, which makes me wonder how can a transaction be partial?

What could have caused the partial transaction and how does it happen? Is there a way to prevent such partial transactions from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this a partial transaction issue. The `null` result from `set` means the key already existed when the transaction started and was not set (because of the `NX` flag).

From [redis docs](https://redis.io/commands/set#return-value):

> a Null Bulk Reply is returned if the SET operation was not performed because the user specified the **NX** or XX option but the condition was not met